# In UML class diagrams, is there specific differences between operations and constructors?

Tags: uml

I'm taking a Data Analysis course, we're covering UML class diagrams. I keep getting confused by the terminology of methods (operations) and constructors. What is the difference between a method and a constructor? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated, the light bulb for this just hasn't lit yet and hope some outside perspectives will help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Some of the confusion has historical reasons where terms were defined only partially (or not at all). The current UML spec 2.5 defines on p. 114

> **9.6.3.1 Operations**
>
> An Operation is a BehaviorialFeature of an Interface, DataType, or Class. An Operation may be directly invoked on instances of its *featuringClassifiers*. The Operation specifies the name, type, Parameters, and Constraints for such invocations.

Sounds a bit like blurb, but basically this is what a programmer would call a function.

**Method** in contrast (which formerly has been used alternatively to Operation) is defined on p. 13

> For example, an operation owned by a class may have a related method that defines its detailed behavior.

So the method is the "how to" of an operation and can be described by various means like e.g. a StateMachine and more.

Finally a Constructor is a certain operation which by is executed during initialization of an object. On p. 15:

> Therefore, when modeling the detailed behavior of the instantiation of a classifier, it is a modeler responsibility to ensure that the modeled behavior carries out the proper initialization of any attributes with default values once the object is created. (This is often done by encapsulating the instantiation behavior for a class in a constructor operation – see sub clause 11.4 – in which case the initialization of the attributes becomes an implicit postcondition for the constructor.)

Comment: Now, if you could explain why <<new>> (invocation of constructor?) is a *dashed* arrow in sequence diagrams whereas messages to invoke operations (when they're synchronous as most are) are *solid* arrows, I'd understand even more the difference :-)

Comment: @Fuhrmanator Well, the UML guys just happened to design it this way. A `new` is not just a message since it creates an object before sending the object reference as result. So it's a "different flavor" which they decided to show by using a different rendering.